# Is there a way to loop through a function's parameters in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through the passed parameters of a function/sub and print their values (for debugging).

The annoying way would be to create an array/collection at the start of each function that loads my declared params in a hardcoded way for each function:

```
Function myfunc(foo, bar)
    Dim fPARAMS As New Collection

    fPARAMS.Add foo
    fPARAMS.Add bar

    '...
```

Is there is some built-in way to get an array-like object that has my parameters?

Something like;

```
fPARAMS() = built_in_func_that_returns_my_params()
```

I haven't found anything on Google nor in SO.

Comment: No. You'd have to pass them as one `ParamArray` argument to be able to loop through them.

Comment: Another way would be to use class variables, so a class called, clsVariables say, then variables, A,B and C in this, but privately declared, but you would get them from properties, so `Property get A() as integer` then in the code for this, have `"Variable A used : " & now()` so we'd call like `TestFunction(clsVariables.A,clsVariables.B)`    Each time `clsVariables.A` is called instead of `A` it will involve a work around I believe though, no easy way I think.

Comment: @Rory - that's what I feared (and should've expected from VBA) :-(

Comment: @ArcherBird If it makes you feel better, C# has the same limitation. Admittedly, you can use reflection, but I don't think that's what you are after; you're looking for something like the Javascript `arguments` object.